# How to run a bash script automatically after completing any Taskwarrior task?

Tags: bash, taskwarrior

I would like to automate the execution of a bash script each time I complete any Taskwarrior task. How can I set up Taskwarrior to run this script automatically after completing any task?

I have written the bash script, and it runs correctly when executed manually. However, I'm not sure how to trigger it automatically after completing a Taskwarrior task.

I have looked into Taskwarrior's hooks feature, but I'm not sure which hook I should use and how to configure it to run my bash script. Can someone provide a step-by-step guide on how to set up a Taskwarrior hook to run a bash script after completing any task?

Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own shell function in `~/.bashrc` that runs your taskwarrior command and the bash script.

```
t() {
    task $@
    ./shell_script.sh
}
```